# Wordpress Video Player Suggestion

Tags: html, video, wordpress, video-player

I need a plugin for wordpress website which have following qualities:

1. subtitles
2. quality selecttion

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some wordpress plugins which may help you :-

1. FV Flowplayer Video Player
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/fv-wordpress-flowplayer/
2. Spider Video Player
   https://wordpress.org/plugins/player/
3. MediaElement.js - HTML5 Video & Audio Player